# Convergence of empirical distribution for composition of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

What I have in mind are $n$ realization draws from a distribution with density $F(x)$. Then, for each $x_n$, there is a draw $y_n$ from density $G[x_n,H(F^{-1}(x_n)),y]$, with $x_n$ and $F^{-1}(x_n)$ being parameters.
As $n\rightarrow \infty$, will the empirical distribution of $y_n$ converge to $G[F(x),H(1),y]$ or something?

Sorry if I wasn't able to phrase the question clearly enough, as I only have the knowledge of undergrad level probability theory.

Comment: As you're written it, $Y_n$ is an independent, identically distributed (iid) sequence. It always has the same (unconditional) distribution. The fact that the distribution is conditionally dependent on $X_n$ doesn't matter... the $X_n$ are iid and the distribution of $X$ is just averaged over to get $Y$'s unconditional distribution.  Thus $Y_n$ converges in distribution, but in  the rather boring way where the distribution is the same for all $n.$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am still very confused... In my understanding, each $y_n$ has it's own conditional distribution. But as $n\rightarrow \infty$, and if we stack all the realizations of $y_n$ together, we get an empirical distribution, and it should converge to a form that washes away all uncertainty from random draws?

Comment: First off, it doesn't seem to me that all this business about $F^{-1}(x_n)$ is essential to the question. Basically you have a iid sequence $X_n$ and a sequence sequence $Y_n$ where each $Y_n$ is drawn from some distribution whose parameters depend on $X_n.$ So we can write the conditional distribution of $Y_n$ on $X_n$ as $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ (This is the same for all $n$ so we omit $n$). Then you can write the unconditional distribution of $Y$ as $$f_Y(y) = \int f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)dx $$ (for the case of continuous distribution). $Y_n$ is just an iid sequence from this distribution.

Comment: So in answer to your question, yes the $Y_n$ has its own uncondtiional distribution that averages over $X_n$ and this is the distribution you'll see realize empirically with a lot of data.

Comment: Great! Thanks for clarifying!